# Checking next Line to then implement where the line should go to

Tags: python, pseudocode

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement having a text file with lines having both lines of words and then lines of numbers. What I want to try and do is read the lines under the words then the saving those words to a list variable.

New to coding so bear with me please.

Example text File:

```
 Hello World
 4, 3, 2
 3, 4, 2
 2, 3, 4
 Change the World
 5, 3, 9
 3, 9, 5
 Save the World
 1, 2, 3
```

My Pseudo Code:

```
 Open File
 Read the First Line
 If the current-line[0] is Letter then:
   parse the current Line
   save the parsed to a Word list
   Go to the next line
 If the current-line[0] is a Number then:
   parse the current Line
   save the parsed line in a list
   read the next line
   If the next line has another number then:
      parse line
      save it to the previous parsed-line list
      #Keep Checking if the next line begins with a number
      #if it doesn't and the next line begins with a letter go back up to the previous statement
```

My question:
    How can I tell python to check the next line with out leaving my current line and then checking which "if" statement the next line should go to?

Example Code: *Simplified*

```
 def parse():
    return parse

 txtopen = open("txt","r")
 line = txtopen.readline()
 while line:
  if line[0] is not between 0 or 9::
   parse = parse(line)
   wordlist.append(parse)
  if line[0] in between  0 and 9:
   parse = parse(line)
   list = list.extend(parse)
   '''
   This is where i cant figure out how to read the next line and check
   '''
   finallist = list.append(list)
  line = txtopen.readline()
```

Output:

```
   wordList : ["Hello Word", "Change the World", "Save the World"]
   numberList : [[4,3,2,3,4,2,2,3,4],[5,3,9,3,9,5],[1,2,3]]
```

Any help within my logic with my pseudo code would be fantastic or anything in general that can help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @kindall i love the edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the next line you can do something like this.

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    current_line_index = 0
    next_line = lines[current_line_index + 1]
    print next_line
```

here is how I would solve this particular problem.

```
import csv

word_list = []
number_list = []

with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        if line[0].strip().isdigit():
            number_list.append(line)
        else:
            word_list.append(line)

print number_list
print word_list
```